# linq findall with multiple predicates

Tags: c#, linq, predicates

In C# I have an object with a name and surname property and have created a list of these objects, `List<person>`.

I'd like to filter this `List<person>` basing it on a name and a surname, but in the list some person can have surname null, so I'd like to filter for name only if name is not null and for surname only if it's not null.

I'm not able to do it with findall, cause it accepts only a predicate

```
m_cPersons.FindAll(q => q.Name != null && q.Name.ToUpper().Contains(name));
```

How can I add two predicates?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the `List<T>.FindAll(...)` method, use the LINQ `Where(Func<TSource,bool> predicate)` extension method:

```
m_cPersons.Where(q => q.Name != null && q.Name.ToUpper().Contains(name));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, you can achieve filtering basing on name and surname with `FindAll`:

```
m_cPersons.FindAll(q =>
    (q.Name == null ||
        q.Name.IndexOf(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    &&
    (q.LastName == null ||
        q.LastName.IndexOf(lastName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
);
```

Using `IndexOf(... StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` is more reliable than `ToUpper().Contains(...)` (see [Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/444798)).